# How do I make the background image fit different resolutions and browser sizes when re adjusted

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make my `background-image` be adjustable to different resolutions and browser sizes but it still doesn't fit well leaving a large white space on the right when the browser or resolution is adjusted for scrolling left or right, but it fits well on my PC when in full screen. My buttons also don't adjust to the recommended browser size. Can anyone be of assistance.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11AM3.png)

```
header {
  background-image: url('laptop-4-wallpaper-3840x2160-1024x576.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: inherit;
} 
    <header>

    <div class = "row">
    <ul class ="main-nav">
        <li> <a href = ""> HOME </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = ""> ABOUT </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = ""> SERVICES</a> </li>
        <li> <a href = ""> NEWS </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = ""> CONTACT </a> </li>
        <li> <a href = ""> FAQ </a> </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = "banner">
        <img class = "banner-image" src = "pngkey.com-apple-logo-png-170591.png" >
    </div>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover` should do what you need. Can you show a live example?

Comment: could you please share the HTML for the header element ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Comment: you can use media queries